# Put dictionary key and item in columns without transposing

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that creates a dictionary with over 30k entries, My problem now is that I would like to have these entries show in columns in excel Excel has a maximum number of column entries that doesn't allow me to put my keys in and then transpose them. I would like all the keys to be in one column and all the values in another.

Question: Is there a way around this?

Comment: You should include the macro which creates your dictionary (or at least the relevant output portion), to see how this data is created. The key will be changing the macro itself so that it generates the entries in 2 columns rather than 2 rows. Also, if you have limited VBA experience it is not recommended to simply run macros that are outside of your understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub HTH()
 Dim vArray As Variant
 Dim lLoop As Long
 Dim rCell As Range

 With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    .CompareMode = 1
    For Each rCell In Range("B1:I3022")
        vArray = Split(rCell.Value, " ")
        For lLoop = LBound(vArray) To UBound(vArray)
            If Not .Exists(vArray(lLoop)) Then
                .Add vArray(lLoop), 1
            Else
                .Item(vArray(lLoop)) = .Item(vArray(lLoop)) + 1
            End If
        Next lLoop
    Next rCell
    MsgBox ("there are " & .Count & "Keys")
    Dim keyArray, itemArray, resultArray
    keyArray = .Keys
    itemArray = .Items
    ReDim resultArray(LBound(keyArray) To UBound(keyArray), 0 To 1)
    For i = LBound(keyArray) To UBound(keyArray)
        resultArray(i, 0) = keyArray(i)
        resultArray(i, 1) = itemArray(i)
    Next i
    Range("L1").Resize(UBound(resultArray) + 1, 2) = resultArray
 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You should flesh out your answer to indicate the link between what the OP wants and what you are providing here (ie: linking the terms and your assumptions about the form of his/her data). Simply providing an undocumented macro to someone with limited VBA experience is not good practice.